# Failed to enable BPF LSM when booting in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, bpfilter

I want to enable the BPF LSM, I have added

```
lsm=lockdown,capability,yama,apparmor,bpf
```

to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, and run `update-grub`. After rebooting, it still  displays `lockdown,capability,yama,apparmor` for `cat /sys/kernel/security/lsm`.

The `cat /proc/cmdline` displays

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=a94e991b-4a4b-42ae-9729-ef5199478c48 ro debian-installer/custom-installation=/custom find_preseed=/preseed.cfg auto preseed/file=/floppy/preseed.cfg automatic-ubiquity noprompt priority=critical locale=en_US console-setup/modelcode=evdev lsm=lockdown,capability,yama,apparmor,bpf
```

My kernel version is `5.8.0-48-generic` from `uname -r`.